# How to install python modules when installed using make altinstall?

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently on Debian GNU/Linux and I have python2.7 and python3.5 pre-installed so I then again installed python3.8 with make altinstall.

Now I have two versions of python3 and python3.8. Then I installed tensorflow module using pip3 install tensorflow-gpu and when I opened python3.8 and tried to import tensorflow It's says module not found.

If that's the case how can I install modules for python3.8?

Comment: What's your `PYTHONPATH`? Is it still pointing at 3.5?

Comment: How can I know where it's pointing towards?

Comment: If you just run `pip3 --version` it should tell you what directory it's pointing at ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html Mention here how to install respective python library.

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.8 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.8
```